# IF ELSE Query on MYSQL

Tags: mysql, if-statement

How can i print the below structure

```html
+--------+------------+
| Male   | Female     |
+--------+------------+
| Salman |   Meena    |
| Govinda|   Kanika   |
+--------+------------+
```

details from table employee

```
employeename    sex
---------------------
Salman          male
Meena           female
Kanika          female
Govinda         male
```

I am using below query but output is not as expected as I need.

**Query**:

```
select
    (if(emp1.sex='male',emp1.employeename,'')) as Male,
    (if(emp1.sex='female',emp1.employeename,'')) as Female
from employee emp1;
```

```html
actual output: 

+--------+------------+
| Male   | Female     |
+--------+------------+
| Salman |          |
|        |   Meena    |
|        |   Kanika   |
| Govinda|            |
+--------+------------+
```

Comment: You'd have to use a self-join to do this in SQL.  However, fields in a row are typically related.  Why does Salman appear on the same row as Meena?  Why Govinda with Kanika?  And remember, a table is an **unordered** set of rows.

Comment: Hi @Bacaon Bits  It  looks like silly for  Salman appear on the same row as Meena. but this was the requirement

Comment: use the case then estructure https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html

Comment: How is the relationship between male and female? For example, from your table, there are two possible result sets: 1) (Salman, Meena), (Govinda, Kanika) OR 2) (Salman, Kanika), (Govinda, Meena). So what is the rule describing which male belongs to which female?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Comment: @Binarus There is no relationship between Salman, meena and Govind, Kanika .   Just want to print All male in one column and all females in one column